# Datatable not working with javascript settimeout fuction?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I want output of the table here-

It actually give output. Datatable features like responsive, sorting, searching are not working. But When I remove the 3000 milli second delay, it works perfectly.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('tbl_display').innerHTML = '<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap"><thead><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>ASIN</th><th>Image</th><th>Reimburse</th><th>Total Units</th><th>Total Sales</th><th>Profit</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="odd"><td><span class="text-primary">SW20 16GB memory</span></td><td>B0245448898</td><td><img src="https://www.scinex.com/uploads/products/PD266/1537943878396_100.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:25px; height:auto" /></td><td>--</td><td>--</td><td>$30.00</td><td>$13.00</td></tr><tr class="even"><td><span class="text-primary">Scinex Bluetooth headset</span></td><td>B0000089451</td><td><img src="https://www.scinex.com/uploads/products/PD266/1537943878396_100.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:25px; height:auto" /></td><td>--</td><td>--</td><td>$7.00</td><td>$3.00</td></tr><tr class="odd"><td><span class="text-primary">SW30</span></td><td>B0245448898</td><td><img src="https://www.scinex.com/uploads/products/PD266/1537943878396_100.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:25px; height:auto" /></td><td>Refund</td><td>--</td><td>$39.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr></tbody></table>';
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="sales-info-table" id="tbl_display">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause: by the time your "datatable" script runs, the DOM won't be ready.

Solution: since you are already using jQuery, checkout [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.

Comment: thanks, But didn't understand as I'm using datatables for the first time.
this is the actual page - scinex.com/cnp/dashboard.html

Answer (score 0):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

See [Jquery $( document ).ready() documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(
        function(){
            document.getElementById('tbl_display').innerHTML='<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap"><thead><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>ASIN</th><th>Image</th><th>Reimburse</th><th>Total Units</th><th>Total Sales</th><th>Profit</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="odd"><td><span class="text-primary">SW20 16GB memory</span></td><td>B0245448898</td><td><img src="https://www.scinex.com/uploads/products/PD266/1537943878396_100.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:25px; height:auto" /></td><td>--</td><td>--</td><td>$30.00</td><td>$13.00</td></tr><tr class="even"><td><span class="text-primary">Scinex Bluetooth headset</span></td><td>B0000089451</td><td><img src="https://www.scinex.com/uploads/products/PD266/1537943878396_100.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:25px; height:auto" /></td><td>--</td><td>--</td><td>$7.00</td><td>$3.00</td></tr><tr class="odd"><td><span class="text-primary">SW30</span></td><td>B0245448898</td><td><img src="https://www.scinex.com/uploads/products/PD266/1537943878396_100.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:25px; height:auto" /></td><td>Refund</td><td>--</td><td>$39.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr></tbody></table>';
        });      
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, my idea is bring data from ajax so that I can work with the filters. this is the actual page - 
https://www.scinex.com/cnp/dashboard.html